# SQL server 2012 select row counts from a variable number of tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have the following query

```
select count(*) as row_count
       , UN_PART
       , 'ABC_PARAM_DETA' as TABLE_NAME
from ABC_PARAM_DETA
group by UN_PART
```

what I would like to do is extend this to use it from a select list rather than a single table as I have multiple tables with UN_PART eg

```
select count(*) as row_count
       , UN_PART
       , '@var_table' as TABLE_NAME
from (Select TABLE_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where COLUMN_NAME = 'UN_PART')
group by UN_PART
```

Anyone any ideas on how to achieve this

Comment: store all the table names inside temp table, for each table name dynamically generate SQL Query (as string) and execute using [sp_executesql](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Output') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Output

CREATE TABLE #Output
    (ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
     TableName NVARCHAR(MAX),
     RowCnt INT)

INSERT INTO #Output (TableName)
Select C.TABLE_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES T ON C.TABLE_NAME = T.TABLE_NAME 
WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'UN_PART' AND T.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'

DECLARE @Step AS INT = 1

WHILE @Step <= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Output) BEGIN
    DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SELECT @TableName = TableName FROM #Output WHERE ID = @Step

    SET @SQL = 'UPDATE #Output SET RowCnt = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' + @TableName + ') WHERE TableName = ''' + @TableName + ''''

    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL

    SET @Step = @Step + 1
END

SELECT * FROM #Output

DROP TABLE #Output
```

Comment: Thanks richard, that does work but in this case it doesnt include the group by table the output should be something like                          

Count  UN_PART  TABLE_NAME
43 2 ABC_PARAM_DETA
43 3 ABC_PARAM_DETA
43 4 ABC_PARAM_DETA

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested but I think this should work

```
Exec sp_MSforeachtable 
@command1 ='select ''?'', un_part, count(1) from  ?  group by un_part'
,@whereand = ' and object_id in (select o.object_id from sys.objects o
inner join sys.columns c
    on o.object_id = c.object_id
and c.name = ''UN_PART'')'
```

Comment: @oldguy tested with case in my environment and just corrected a couple typos.  Let me know if it works well for you!